# change date format for wsdl

Tags: vb.net, web-services, date, wsdl

I'm trying to use web-service and query weather by dates.

Getting response from server that : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Web-service needs start and end date's and those are in date format, not in string.

I think that proper date format would be '2011-01-01' and trying to use that.
System always change date format which it will send to web-service.

So would I need to reformat date from 1/1/2011 format to 2011-1-1 inside of date, not using tostring formating. How can I do that ?

Comment: `I think that proper date format would be` why do you think that? Is there an official reference? Generally, when using WSDL, dates are dates, format makes sense with strings, which contain dates in them.

Comment: Because my colleague has been able to get data with script in that format. Haven't found reference anywhere.